# What is my strategy for solving inequalities like these?

Tags: inequality

I am trying to determine the solution to:

$$3\lvert2-x\rvert \ge\lvert x+5\rvert-3$$

I looked at some other similar questions here and I tried to follow their strategy by splitting the inequality up into cases:

$$\lvert 2-x\rvert =
\begin{cases}
2-x,  & \text{if $x \le 2$} \\
-2+x, & \text{if $x >2$}
\end{cases}$$

$$\lvert x+5\rvert =
\begin{cases}
x+5,  & \text{if $x \ge -5$} \\
-x-5, & \text{if $x <-5$}
\end{cases}$$

As far as I understand I have three intervals to check:

$$1) \space x<-5 \\2)  \space -5 \le x\le2 \\3) \space x>2$$

Case 1: $3(2-x) \ge -x-5-3 \implies x\le 7$

Case 2: $-3(2-x) \ge (x+5)-3 \implies x\le 1$

Case 3: $-3(2-x) \ge x+5-3 \implies x\ge 4$

Final answer: $$ x \le 1;\space \space     4 \le x\le7$$

My questions:

- I am currently doing this like a robot without really knowing whats going on. What am I trying to figure out when looking at the different cases 1,2,3? In other words, what do the solutions of the cases tell me about my inequality.
- Is there any other strategy I can use to solve these inequalities?
- The solution wolframalpha gives me is $(4, \infty)$ and $(-\infty,1]$. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Was the "14 <= x <= 7" supposed to be "4 <= x <= 7"?  The 4 at least matches up with your case 3, the 14 seems out of place.

Comment: @KurtSchwanda Yes. For some reason I added a $1$. I edited my post.

Comment: For your three cases, you need to restrict those to the corresponding intervals:  Case 1: x <=7 and x < -5 becomes just x < -5.  Case 2: x <= 1 and -5 <= x <= 2 becomes -5 <= x <= 1.  Case 3: x >= 4 and x > 2 becomes just x >= 4.  Also, those three cases are separate from one another, so you want to combine them with "or": x < -5 OR -5 <= x <= 1 OR x >= 4.  But look how you can combine cases 1 and 2: x < -5 or -5 <= x <= 1 becomes just x <= 1.  That's your (-∞, 1] and case 3, the x >= 4 would be [4, ∞).  Did a [ become ( when you were retyping what Wolfram Alpha gave you?

Comment: @KurtSchwanda Yes I made a mistake copying it. You are right about the intervals. Your answer and the other answers helped me understand now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start of with the expression 
$$3\lvert2-x\rvert \ge\lvert x+5\rvert-3$$
and you are looking for all the possible $x \in \mathbb{R}$ that make this inequality true. Now, why are we breaking it up into those intervals? Well that is because of how absolute value is defined:

> $|a| = \begin{cases}
> a, \quad  \ \ \ \text{if}\ \  a\geq 0 \\
> -a, \quad \text{if}\ \ a < 0.
> \end{cases}$

Notice that:

- If $x<-5$ then $(x+5)$ is negative and $(2-x)$ is positive, hence by definition $|2-x|= 2-x$, and $|x+5| = -(x+5) = -x-5.$
- If $-5 \leq x<2 $ then $(2-x)$ is still positive, and $x+5$ is now also positive. Hence by definition $|2-x|= 2-x $ but now $|x+5| =  x+5.$
- If $x\geq2$ then $(2-x)$ turns negative and $(x+5)$ is positive, hence $|2-x| = -(2-x)=x-2$ and $|x+5| = x+5.$

Now, we sum up the possible cases:

- Case 1: $x < -5.$ Then  the expression $\ \ $ 
  $3\lvert2-x\rvert \ge\lvert x+5\rvert-3$
  is equivalent to
  $$3(2-x) \geq -x-5-3$$
  which reduces to $x \leq 7$. Then the possible solutions in this case are those such that $x < -5$ AND $x \leq 7$, which is simply $x <-5$.
- Case 2: $-5\leq x < 2.$ Then  the expression $\ \ $ 
  $3\lvert2-x\rvert \ge\lvert x+5\rvert-3$
  is equivalent to
  $$3(2-x) \geq x+5-3$$
  which reduces to $x \leq 1$. Thus now the possible solutions are $x$ such that $-5 \leq x <2$ AND $x \leq 1$, which is the interval$ -5 \leq x \leq 1.$
- Case 3: $x \geq 2.$ Then  the expression $\ \ $ 
  $3\lvert2-x\rvert \ge\lvert x+5\rvert-3$
  is equivalent to
  $$3(x-2) \geq x+5-3$$
  which reduces to $x \geq 4$. Thus now the possible solutions are $x$ such that $x \geq 2$ AND $x \geq 4$, which is simply $x \geq 4$.

To this we can conclude that the following intervals fit the criteria: 
$x<-5,\ -5 \leq x \leq 1$ and $x \geq 4$. We can type it more neatly so the solution is given by $ x \in (-\infty,1] \cup [4, \infty).$

Comment: Thank you very much for that detailed answer. It all makes a lot of sense now. Just one question. Why did you include the case $x=2$ in case 3 and not in case 2 (i.e.$-5 \le x \le 2$)? Can I just choose where it include these?

Comment: Well, yes, it depends on how you define absolute value. Under the definition I presented the correct thing would be to include $x=2$ under case 3, since $x=2$ is the first point in which the expression inside the absolute value becomes _greater or equal_ than zero . Notice that if you consider it in case $2$ it would yield the same answer, since it would boil down to  if $|0| = 0  $ or $|0| = -0$ which is the same. However, for the sake of consistency I would recommend to stick with one definition.

Answer (score 1):

If you have $a \ge b$, where $a$ and $b$ are relatively simple absolute value expressions, one strategy might be to graph $y = a$ and $y = b$ on the same coordinate axes.

So in this particular case, you would graph $y = 3|2−x|$ and $y = |x+5|−3$.

That may make it easier to determine where the graph of $y = 3|2−x|$ is "above" the graph of $y = |x+5|−3$, in other words where $ 3|2−x| \ge |x+5|−3$.

You can then use your systematic, algebraic approach to determine the exact boundaries for your solution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But there must be something wrong with my algebra approach since I don't get the solutions that mathematica proposes.

Answer (score 1):

You have made at least three mistakes.

1) Solution for case 2 is just plain wrong, please check it.

2) You have to combine intervals with solutions to draw the right conclusion. In case 1) the interval is $x\lt -5$ and the solution for that interval is $x\le7$. You have to **combine** (intersect) the solution with the interval. So in case 1) you have only $x\lt -5$ as part of your final solution. The final solution is a union of three different cases.

3) Equation for case 3 looks exactly the same as case 2?!

It might look mechanical but this approach is, in my opinion, the best one. Even if it is not, you still have to learn to use it properly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I see that I made some silly mistakes. "you have to combine (intersect) the solution with the interval." That makes a lot of sense. What if I can't combine them? For example $x>1$ and I get the solution $x<-2$. Would I just have NO SOLUTION for this interval?

Comment: @Nullspace You are right, in that case you have no solution.